# Issue with the submitAdapterAuthentication() method of the ChallengeHandler in MobileFirst v.6.3

Tags: callback, ibm-mobilefirst, promise

We have an issue with the submitAdapterAuthentication() method of the ChallengeHandler in IBM MobileFirst v.6.3.

We assign callback functions to the properties 'onSuccess' and 'onFailure' in [the options object](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_the_options_object.html?lang=en).

We then provide the options object to submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, options) and execute it.

```
var ch = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler(securityTest);

//////////////////

function login (user, pass) {

  tempUser = {username: user, password: pass};
  userObj.user = user;
  var auth = "Basic " + window.btoa(user + ":" + pass);

    var invocationData = {
     parameters: [auth, user],
     adapter: "SingleStepAuthAdapter",
     procedure: "submitLogin"
    };

    var options = {
      onSuccess: iWon,
      onFailure: iLost,
      invocationContext: {invocationData: invocationData},
      timeout: 10000
    };

    ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, options);

});

function iWon(response) {
    WL.Logger.debug('Login success! Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));

   //update user info, as somehow isUserAuthenticated return false without it
    WL.Client.updateUserInfo(function(response) {
        WL.Logger.debug('Updated User Info success! Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}

function iLost(response) {
    WL.Logger.debug('ERROR. Login failed! Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Neither the onSuccess (iWon) or the onFailure (iLost) is called after executing submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, options).

How do we know if the authentication was successful?

Which options, events, callbacks or promises shall we look for and use?

We have also posted the issue here: 
[submitAdapterAuthentication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690354/worklight-submitadapterauthentication-not-working/)

Comment: is that the complete JS code? you are missing `ch.isCustomResponse = function(response){...}` and `ch.handleChallenge = function(response){...}`

Comment: "*We have also posted the issue here*" - Is that the same question?

Comment: They posted the question as an answer (will probably be removed soon)

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the definition of the functions

```
ch.isCustomResponse = function(response){...}
ch.handleChallenge = function(response){...}
```

Your code should look more like this

```
var ch = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler(securityTest);

ch.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
  if (!response||!response.responseJSON||response.responseText === null) {
       return false;
  }
     if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
};


ch.handleChallenge = function(response){
  var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;

    if (authRequired == true){
        // handle the case when authentication is needed, i.e., show login form etc.


        if (response.responseJSON.errorMessage) {
      // authentication failed, show a message to the user indicating what went wrong

      // call the login failed function or move it's contents here
      iLost(response);
    }

    } else if (authRequired == false){
          // no authentication is needed 
          ch.submitSuccess();

      // call the login success function or move it's contents here
      iWon(response);
    }
};



//////////////////

function login (user, pass) {

  tempUser = {username: user, password: pass};
  userObj.user = user;

  // is the first parameter expected by submitLogin the username or the
  // Basic Authentication encoded string ???
  var auth = "Basic " + window.btoa(user + ":" + pass);

  var invocationData = {
     parameters: [auth, user],
     adapter: "SingleStepAuthAdapter",
     procedure: "submitLogin"
  };

  ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {});

});


function iWon(response) {
    WL.Logger.debug('Login success! Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));

   //update user info, as somehow isUserAuthenticated return false without it
    WL.Client.updateUserInfo(function(response) {
        WL.Logger.debug('Updated User Info success! Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}

function iLost(response) {
    WL.Logger.debug('ERROR. Login failed! Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

For more information on adapter-based authentication visit http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_adapter_based_authenticator.html?lang=en

You should also check the getting started module on adapter-based authentication for hybrid applications https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-hybrid-applications/