# Order function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to make `submitAdapterAuthentication()` function to work the first `getUserRoles()` function, but with the current implementation of the `getUserRoles()` function is being executed first that `submitAdapterAuthentication()`. How can I fix this?

```
    checkOnline().then(function(onl) {
        userObj.isLoginOnline = onl;
    }).then(function() {
        submitAdapterAuthentication(user, pass);
    }).then(function() {
        getUserRoles();
    });


function submitAdapterAuthentication(user, pass) {
    var invocationData = {
        parameters : [ user, pass ],
        adapter : "adapterAuth",
        procedure : "submitLogin"
    };

    ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {
        onFailure : function(error) {
            WL.Logger.log("ERROR ON FAIL: ", error);
        },
        onSuccess : function() {
            WL.Client.updateUserInfo({
                onSuccess : function() {
                    //return promise
                    WL.Client.updateUserInfo({
                        onSuccess : function() {
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

 // my function to obtain roles 
    // It should be performed after submitAdapterAuthentication
    function getUserRoles(){
        var arrayRoles = [];
        var attributes = WL.Client.getUserInfo(realm, "attributes");
        if(attributes){
            if(attributes.roles){
                arrayRoles.push(attributes.roles);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When chaining promises, if you return anything but another promise from a then() callback, the resulting promise will be resolved immediately with the value `undefined`.

In order to make sure your callbacks are executed in the order you specified, just make sure each callback is returning a promise at the end. If you want to return some value from a callback, wrap it in a `$q.when()`. In this case it looks like you are not using any intermediary return values, so you can just wrap any arbitrary value in a $q.when() to make sure a promise is returned:

```
checkOnline().then(function(onl) {
    userObj.isLoginOnline = onl;
    return $q.when(true);
}).then(function() {
    submitAdapterAuthentication(user, pass);
    return $q.when(true);
}).then(function() {getUserRoles();});
```

Based on your latest edit, it looks like `ch.submitAdapterAuthentication()` is likely returning a promise. If this is the case, you should return this promise from the function:
`return ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {...`
And then return this promise in the then callback:
`then(function() {return submitAdapterAuthentication(user, pass);})`

If `ch.submitAdapterAuthentication()` does not return a $q promise, you will have to wrap it yourself:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {
    onFailure : function(error) {
        WL.Logger.log("ERROR ON FAIL: ", error);
        deferred.reject(error);
    },
    onSuccess : function() {
        WL.Client.updateUserInfo({
            onSuccess : function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        });
    }
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: I try, but 'attributes' in getUserRoles() only return {}, as if the submitAdapterAuthentication had not happened. My submitAdapterAuthentication is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690354/submitadapterauthentication-not-working

Comment: Pablo, I see that you accepted the answer, does that mean you got it to work? If you're still having issues, let me know and I'll try to look at this a little deeper later this evening.